# Editing razor elements

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I'm very new to razor, so bare with me. Anyway, I'm aware that you can make eg. a `<p>` element a variable that you can then change with C#, but I wanted to know if it's possible to edit the elements, in a way Javascript allows, such as `.innerHTML`. And if it was, how would I get the element, like `document.getElementById(...)`.

Comment: Are we talking Razor or Blazor.  If Blazor then I think you have the wrong end of the stick on how you manipulate data in elements.  Show us a real code example in a razor component context.

Comment: For Blazor: You shouldn't need this, you are trying to duplicate what Blazor does: manipulate the HTML. And you shouldn't do it because you would interfere with that.

Answer (score 0):

In Razor, all elements and their attributes are actually nothing but *strings*.
E.g. this in Razor:

```
<p class="@className">@(text)</p>
```

will execute internally as something similar to this:

```
output.Write("<p class=\"" + HtmlEncode(className) + "\">" + HtmlEncode(text) + "</p>");
```

You can fully control what attributes and content the `<p>` will have. But in the end it all becomes **plain text** that gets written to an output stream, and that is the only task of Razor rendering.

To manipulate it after rendering the HTML output, your only option is to do it client side, in the browser, using Javascript.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to Razor components. It seems like you answered as if it was asking about Razor Pages, but this is a Blazor question.

Comment: @MisterMagoo:it's a Razor __and__ Blazor question... Both tags are there.

Comment: The question was Razor.  @Peter B answered it as such.  The rest of us read between the lines and guessed it was about Blazor because of the Blazor Tag.  I asked to clarify and the questioner hasn't come back.

Comment: @MrCaka: "that you can then change with C#"